# How remove data from an array in aggrigation whithout disturbing outside data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Here I am trying to get entire data but if date less then current then do not fetch that date from the database.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ab5"), 
"highlights" : [
    "highlights-1", 

], 
"notes" : [
    "Listen"
], 
"soldout" : false, 
"active" : false, 
"operator" : ObjectId(""), 
"title" : "2D1N Awesome trip to Knowhere 99", 
"destinations" : [
    {
        "coordinatesType" : "Point", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ab6"), 

    }
], 
"difficulty" : "Easy", 
"duration" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ab7"), 
    "days" : NumberInt(2), 
    "nights" : NumberInt(1)
}, 
"media" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ab8"), 
    "images" : [

    ], 
    "videos" : [

    ]
}, 
"description" : "Surrounded ", 
"inclusions" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId(""), 
        "text" : "Included"
    }
], 
"itinerary" : "Surrounded .", 
"thingsToCarry" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId(""), 
        "text" : "Yourself"
    }
], 
"exclusions" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId(""), 
        "text" : "A Lot"
    }
], 
"policy" : "Fully refundable 7777 Days before the date of Experience", 
"departures" : [
    {
        "dates" : [
            ISODate("2019-11-19T02:44:58.989+0000"), 
            ISODate("2019-11-23T17:19:47.878+0000")
        ], 
        "_id" : ObjectId(""), 
        "bookingCloses" : "2 Hours Before", 
        "maximumSeats" : NumberInt(20), 
        "source" : {
            "coordinatesType" : "Point", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ac2"), 
            "code" : "code", 
            "name" : "Manali", 
            "state" : "Himachal Pradesh", 
            "region" : "North", 
            "country" : "India", 
            "coordinates" : [
                23.33, 
                NumberInt(43), 
                NumberInt(33)
            ]
        }, 
        "pickupPoints" : [
            {
                "coordinatesType" : "Point", 
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ac3"), 
                "name" : "name-3", 
                "address" : "address-3", 
                "time" : "time-3", 
                "coordinates" : [
                    23.33, 
                    NumberInt(43), 
                    NumberInt(33)
                ]
            }
        ], 
        "prices" : {
            "3" : NumberInt(5)
        }, 
        "mrps" : {
            "3" : NumberInt(5)
        }, 
        "markup" : NumberInt(25), 
        "discount" : NumberInt(0), 
        "b2m" : {
            "3" : NumberInt(5)
        }, 
        "m2c" : {
            "3" : 6.25
        }, 
        "minimumOccupancy" : NumberInt(3), 
        "maximumOccupancy" : NumberInt(3)
    }
], 
"bulkDiscounts" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ac4")
    }
],     
}
```

In this I am trying to get all the data except the date section should be different. Means I should get my output as below

```
{
            "_id": "5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ab5",
            "highlights": [
                "highlights-1",
                "highlights-2",
                "highlights-3",
                "highlights-4",
                "highlights-5"
            ],
            "notes": [
                "Listen"
            ],
            "soldout": false,
            "active": false,
            "operator": "5d5d84e8c89fbf00063095f6",
            "title": "2D1N Awesome trip to Knowhere 99",
            "destinations": [
                {
                    "code": "code",
                    "name": "Manali",
                    "coordinates": [
                        23.33,
                        43,
                        33
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "difficulty": "Easy",
            "duration": {
                "_id": "5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ab7",
                "days": 2,
                "nights": 1
            },
            "media": {
                "_id": "5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ab8",
                "images": [


            ],
            "videos": []
        },
        "description": "Surrounded.",
        "inclusions": [
            {
                "_id": "5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5abe",
                "text": "Included"
            }
        ],
        "itinerary": "Surrounded",
        "thingsToCarry": [
            {
                "_id": "5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5abf",
                "text": "Yourself"
            }
        ],
        "exclusions": [
            {
                "_id": "5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ac0",
                "text": "A Lot"
            }
        ],
        "policy": "Fully refundable 7777 Days before the date of Experience",
        "departures": [
            {
                "dates": [
                    "2019-11-23T17:19:47.878Z"
                ],
                "_id": "5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ac1",
                "bookingCloses": "2 Hours Before",
                "maximumSeats": 20,
                "source": {
                    "code": "code",
                    "name": "Manali",
                    "coordinates": [
                        23.33,
                        43,
                        33
                    ]
                },
                "pickupPoints": [
                    {
                        "coordinatesType": "Point",
                        "_id": "5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ac3",
                        "name": "name-3",
                        "address": "address-3",
                        "time": "time-3",
                        "coordinates": [
                            23.33,
                            43,
                            33
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "mrps": {
                    "3": 5
                },
                "markup": 25,
                "discount": 0,
                "b2m": {
                    "3": 5
                },
                "m2c": {
                    "3": 6.25
                },
                "minimumOccupancy": 3,
                "maximumOccupancy": 3
            }
        ],
        "bulkDiscounts": [
            {
                "_id": "5d6fad0f9e0dc027fc6b5ac4"
            }
        ],
        "url": "",


    }
]
```

I mean to say that no difference in output except dates array. If dates are less than current date then no need to fetch else fetch from DB with filtered dates array.

Comment: Can you send your query?

Comment: const filter = {
  $match: {
   'departures.dates': { $gt: new Date() }
  }
 };
This query filtering entire document of mongodb but do not want to do this. I just want filter Dates array.

Comment: please see the document above in departures.dates is needed to modified. And I need all the data as it is.  I have provided output also in second document.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is basically `const filter = { $match: { 'departures.dates': { $gt: new Date() } }, {'departures.dates':1}};` to get the data only for dates. You said it is an aggregation but what you have shared is just a query.

Comment: Sorry, not. Actually I need entire data as well as dates also but the date should be grater then current date.

Answer (score 1):

If you use mongo 3.4> then you can try with `$addFields` and `$filter`:

```
myCollection.aggregate([
    {$match: { 
      'departures.dates': {
          $elemMatch: {$gt: new Date()}}
       }
    },
    {$addFields: {
        'departures.dates': {
            $filter: {
                input: '$departures.dates',
                as: 'date',
                cond: {
                    $gt: ['$$date', new Date()]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Date array is empty I am getting

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting my desire output. In my db departures.dates: ["2019-11-21T02:44:58.989Z", "2019-11-18T17:19:47.878Z"]. but in output, I should get 1st date only.

Comment: What do you get with this query?

Comment: Empty Date array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202721/discussion-between-rakesh-kumar-sharma-and-daniyal-lukmanov).

Answer (score 0):

I was missing one terms here that my documnet structure is like below

```
{
  _id: ObjecId(),
  departure: [{
    dates: [Array]
  }]
}
```

So, here is my solution in the below code

```
pipeline = [
    { $unwind: '$departures' },
    {
        $addFields: {
            'departures.dates': {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$departures.dates',
                    as: 'date',
                    cond: {
                        $gt: ['$$date', new Date()]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
```